# how to populate Bottom quota from a stack in excel

Tags: excel

Need help in populating a list of bottom performers who are below 25 percentile 
of the over all list. I have the names of employees in one column and their scores in the adjacent column . i have the value of 25th percentile of the scores.
how can i populate the names of the people in the different sheet who the below the 25th percentile mark.

Comment: Can you share a scrubbed file or image of your spreadsheet? Or at least give us a better idea of the layout of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say our Employee names are in the named range EmpName, and their scores are in the named range EmpScore. The formula you could enter in the first row of the next sheet would be:

```
=IF(SMALL(EmpScore,ROW(A1))<QUARTILE(EmpScore,1),INDEX(EmpName,MATCH(SMALL(EmpScore,ROW(A1)),EmpScore,0)),"")
```

Then copy it down (which will increase only the ROW(A1), selecting the next in the list) far enough to get everybody (extra's will be listed as blank entries). This will also put them in order of lowest to highest.